# smarty relative links with in html templates?

Tags: smarty, smarty3

how do we include style sheets from a template file in smarty?

ca we use a relative path or does it have to be n absolute path?

structure might look like

```
project
|-- library
    |-- css
        |-- style.css
|--template
   |--index.tpl
|--template_c
```

in the `index.tpl` what would be the proper format to access `style.css`?

would it `../library/css/style.css`? or
`/project/library/css/style.css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

If your goal is to have the browser access the css file, you need to specify the path relative to the document root. so, if your project lies within htdocs, it might be `/project/library/css/style.css`.

If your goal is to read the CSS within Smarty (say to inline it) you need to specify the absolute file path (e.g. `/home/users/foo/project/library/css/style.css`)

Accessing files relative to the current template file works with ./file and ../file - but only for {include} and {extends}. Everything else must either be absolute or relative to the CWD (current working directory) of the actually executed script.

Comment: im extending my templates, i am trying to use `./library/css/style.css` and also tried `../library/css/style.css` but it won't point correctly. I know that in the `style.css` I can use `../img/imageName.png` if I wanted to go up a level and access an image from the `img` folder. But how can this concept be done in a template?